# What is different between package.json execution and other build tools in protractor for execution?

Tags: node.js, protractor, gruntjs, karma-jasmine, gulp-protractor

I am new in Protractor Automaton also able to execute test using *npm test* but don't know why we are using any other build tools like gulp, karma and grunt.
i don't know which one is better for script run. we have lots of test script but it's typically manage

package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update && protractor config/conf.js"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think `gulp` and `grunt` is a tool like `maven` in Java world. There are many plugins for them, like plugins for maven to help to compile, minify, copy/move files and so on.

In additionally, you can split those take into separate files to make them can be re-used.

For `scripts` in package.json, you can't make it complex, like `if/else` or more complex logic or reuse. But `gulp` and 'grunt' supports.

Answer (score 0):

From their docs, it seems that protactor is a "end to end test for angular"

So end to end means functionals tests, it's different from unit testing because it not test class or function, it load a website & then try to inspect pages, interact with them...

Protector seems to  be **angular** oriented only

Just for information in your package.json you can just write it:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "webdriver-manager update && protractor config/conf.js"
 },
```